# "sys/mman.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using Code::Blocks 8.02 and I have a question .. every time I try to compile minimad.c (the example that comes with Libmad) I get an error message :

`sys/mman.h: No such file or directory` and of course a bunch of errors to follow :(

I already know that its the memory management library ...
The question is:
Where can I download `<sys/mman.h>`? or if there is another compiler that supports more libraries then Code::Blocks 8.02?

P.S. I already linked mad.h to the compiler and tested out fine so I know there is no problem there ...

Answer (score 14):

Code::Blocks is not a compiler, it's an IDE. And `<sys/mman.h>` is a Unix header and is not available on Windows.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: in fact if you specify <sys/mman.h> under windows it will still pull in the definitions and declarations, that is, provided the code has been ported to win32 platform...by doing #include <sys/mman.h> or any other header file, does not necessarily imply it is unix based because of a forward slash is used. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @tommieb, this has nothing to do with forward slash and everything to do with the fact that all headers under `sys` are traditional Unix APIs. Windows implementations normally provide a few of them - those that are easy to implement, such as `sys/stat.h` or `sys/utime.h` - but not all. The only implementations that might provide `mman.h` is Cygwin and Interix (SFU/SUA).

Answer (score 8):

This is probably too late for the original poster but if anyone needs mman.h for Windows, I've found this: http://code.google.com/p/mman-win32/

You should just be able to open it in VS (I've only done it in VS2010) and build it and then you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling the code? You might need to specify -I for specifying extra include directory which you may have to dig around on your installation /usr/local/include/sys perhaps. Also you would want to use the -L flag to specify the library that gets linked in also. Again dig around to find the correct location.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

WSL or Windows Subsystem for Linux is a great way to develop c programs in a native environment but within windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

I know this is years late but I hope someone finds it useful like I have.