# Cannot open include file: 'sys/mman.h'：No such file or directory

Tags: python, bloom-filter

I am getting this error when I am trying to install pybloomfiltermmap for windows:

> src/mmapbitarray.c(4) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 
>   'sys/mman.h': No such file or directory
>   error: command            'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin \cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

How do I please to fix this?

Comment: [`pybloomfiltermmap` does not support Windows (MSVC)](https://github.com/axiak/pybloomfiltermmap/issues/18). Use a different library.

Answer (score 2):

this problem looks like this one ["sys/mman.h: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810568/sys-mman-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
And  is a Unix header and is not available on Windows.

I suggest you should use  pybloom instead on windows:

```
pip install pybloom
```

and you should use the package like this:

```
from pybloom import BloomFilter
```