# How to add sys/mman.h to MinGW in Windows?

Tags: c++, include, mingw

I'm trying to use the following tool: [Extract Loudest Section](https://github.com/petewarden/extract_loudest_section) in Windows.

I used the following command line to run main.cc `g++ -o main main.cc`

But I've got this message: "fatal error: sys/mman.h: No such file or directory"

However, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13581985/12161821) answer, but I still need more details about how to add the needed files correctly to my compiler?

The "Downloads" page in the link provided by the answer shows:

```
There was an error getting resource 'downloads':
401: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to google-code-archive/v2/code.google.com/mman-win32/downloads-page-1.json.
```

So, I found [this](https://github.com/klauspost/mman-win32) as an alternative resource.

Comment: You'll have better luck rewriting the relevant code to use Win32 syscalls, or running it in WSL or a linux/bsd/etc. VM.